# How to run a script in cassandra-cli command line

Tags: cassandra

I have a script to create a cassandra keyspace and column families

```
cd C:\Tools\apache-cassandra-1.0.12
bin/cassandra-cli -host 127.0.0.1 -f C:\example_script.txt
pause
```

script is included in a batch file. When executed, nothing happens and the script closes.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with '-f' instead of '--f'.

```
bin/cassandra-cli -host 127.0.0.1 -f C:\example_script.txt
```

If that doesn't work, please provide a sample of the commands present in 'example_script.txt'

Comment: It was actually a typo on my part. I have updated the post above to reflect the correction. It still does not work with -f switch. The actual script is fine, when I copy and paste it on the cli console, it works fine. I have no clue what the problem is

Comment: Maybe you must use a specific keyspace using -k option.